# Free JPEG EXIF remover capable of woking directories recursively needed

Tags: jpeg, exif

Do you know one? Ideally it should just get a directory name and run. So, EXIF editor with per file approach is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To recursively remove all metadata from all JPEG images in a hierarchy of directories, use this command with [exiftoo](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)l:

```
exiftool -all= -ext jpg -r DIR
```

where *DIR* is the name of the directory.  Add the `-overwrite_original` option to prevent creating the "_original" backup files.

If you are in Windows this can be done by renaming the Windows executable version of exiftool to this:

```
exiftool(-k -all= -ext jpg -r).exe
```

then dragging and dropping the folder onto the executable.

Comment: That's a cool trick.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state with operating system you are using, but my answers apply to any, anyway.

You should be able to do it with either [**jhead**](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) or [**ExifTool**](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).  I have not used either for some time, but I'm pretty sure there are recursive options, as I usually use them to add Exif data to all photos in a set.  If not, you can always script it using the `for` command.

I used to use jhead, but ExifTool has more options.